# Unable to create oracle data source in Jboss EAP 7.0 server

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I need to create an oracle data source in JBOSS EAP 7.0 server

I deployed **ojdbc6.jar** from the JBOSS management CLI(Command Line Interface) using the below command

```
deploy <PATH_TO_ORACLE_DRIVER_JAR>
```

I could see the server log as below after the driver is deployed

```
01:25:53,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = ojdbc6.jar
01:25:53,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 6) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ojdbc6.jar" (runtime-name : "ojdbc6.jar")
```

But when I try to create oracle data source(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver as driver class) from Jboss management console, I get the below error

```
01:31:35,084 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "OracleDS")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:/OracleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle]",
    "org.wildfly.data-source.OracleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle]"
]}
01:31:35,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.data-source.reference-factory.OracleDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.OracleDS]
      service jboss.data-source-config.OracleDS (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.data-source.OracleDS]
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:/OracleDS, service org.wildfly.data-source.OracleDS]
```

1) May I know what is causing this issue? What dependency is missing? 
2) Is installing JDBC driver as a JAR deployment for data source creation correct method?

Comment: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/how-to-configure-a-datasource-with-jboss-7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Install a JDBC Driver as a Core Module

- Create a directory under $JBOSS_HOME/modules. In this example: "$JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/oracle/jdbc/main".
- Put the the JDBC driver jar (ojdbc6.jar) in this directory.
- Create a module configuration file module.xml:

### Example Oracle JDBC Driver module.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

### Example Oracle Datasource Configuration

```
<datasources>
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>admin</user-name>
        <password>admin</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
  </datasource>
  <drivers>
    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
  </drivers>
</datasources>
```

### Example Management CLI Commands

This example configuration can be achieved by using the following management CLI commands.

### 1. Add the Oracle JDBC driver as a core module.

> module add --name=com.oracle --resources=/path/to/misc/jdbc_drivers/oracle/ojdbc7.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api

### 2. Register the Oracle JDBC driver.

> /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=oracle:add(driver-name=oracle,driver-module-name=com.oracle,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource)

### 3. Add the Oracle datasource.

> data-source add --name=OracleDS --jndi-name=java:jboss/OracleDS --driver-name=oracle --connection-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE --user-name=admin --password=admin --validate-on-match=true --background-validation=false --valid-connection-checker-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker --exception-sorter-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter --stale-connection-checker-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker

Refer the link https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/version-7.0/configuration-guide/#datasource_management

Comment: The best solutions..thanks brother