# Unable to add driver in Jboss EAP 7.1 server

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I am following the documentation here for creating datasources in JBoss EAP 7.1

[JBoss 7.1 doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/datasource_management)

but it fails at the driver creation stage. I am just running a standalone application

I have seen the answers here

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461091/unable-to-create-oracle-data-source-in-jboss-eap-7-0-server)

and here

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049882/jboss-7-oracle-datasource-configuration?rq=1)

but they don't help, at least after reading them I still don't know what the issue is. First I have added a module for oracle jdbc file adding an xml definition and jar file to module/com/oracle/jdbc/main - this works. I then try to add the driver using the cli and get an error. My command is

`/subsystem=datasource/jdbc-driver=oracle:add(driver-name=oracle,driver-module-name=com.oracle.jdbc,driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)`

The error is

`Failed to get the list of the operation properties: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [
    ("subsystem" => "datasource"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "oracle")`

I also tried using the admin gui and get the following response

```
`Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {
        "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle"],
        "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
            "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/access is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle]",
            "org.wildfly.data-source.jdbc/access is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle]"
        ]
    },
    "rolled-back" => true
} `
```

I don't want to edit xml directly so would want to get one of these two approaches working. Any help appreciated!

Edit: Adding module xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.oracle.jdbc">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Where do you see the error? Could you also show your module.xml?

Comment: The error is in the jboss log. I start jboss with the standalone.bat file and the logs then go to standard out on that terminal. I added my module xmlfile to the initial question, the module loads ok though

Comment: That module configuration looks correct. It looks like the driver can't be found though. Is the `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` in the JAR?

Comment: Yes. Opened the jar with zip7. I have ojdbc6.jar\oracle\jdbc\driver\OracleDriver.class. So looks like it is there. Also tried using ojdbc7.jar but same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the module via CLI directly,module.xml is different from what should be created.

```
[JBOSS_bin]$ ./jboss-cli.sh 
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] module add --name=com.oracle --resources=/home/jdbc_test/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar  --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=oracle:add(driver-name=oracle,driver-module-name=com.oracle)
    {"outcome" => "success"}
[standalone@localhost:9990 /]
```

Comment: Get same error. I successfully added the module using the cli like you showed and then tried to register the datasource via cli, the error I get is `/subsystem=datasource/jdbc-driver=oracle:add(driver-name=oracle,driver-module-name=com.oracle,driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)`
Failed to get the list of the operation properties: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [
    ("subsystem" => "datasource"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "oracle")
]"

Comment: Replace your module.xml with below data as it is:<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">

<resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
And add oracle driver it will definitely work

Comment: Copied your xml, only difference now is the version of the jar. I now have  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
 <resources>
  <resource-root path="ojdbc7.jar"/>
 </resources>
 <dependencies>
  <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
 </dependencies>
</module>   I then type the folloing in the cli `/subsystem=datasource/jdbc-driver=oracle:add(driver-name=oracle,driver-module-name=com.oracle.jdbc,driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)` and get the same error

Comment: I understand that you replaced the xml content,but did you create the proper folder structure?Did you try adding the module via CLI?

Comment: The module is in modules/com/oracle/main. As detailed in my response I can add the module mannually or via CLI, that works. When I try to add the datasource via CLI it fails, I get the same error that I have shown in my initial post. Thanks.

Comment: Try creating the module via CLI and then add driver manually in xml .Does that work?Add the driver name and driver-module-name in the driver section in xml and check.

Comment: That worked. I manually added the line <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle"/> to my standalone.xml I could then add the Oracle datasource. Any idea what could have went wrong when using the CLI to add the driver?

Comment: I think the driver-class name parameter was causing the issue.

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: I can't say for sure,but it is not required to add the class-name parameter explicitly,there might be some issue with the class's compatibility

Comment: Don't mean to be a stickler but the question was about getting it working without editing xml which I am still unable to do and can't find any reason on how to do it. I am grateful for your help to get around the problem but still doesn't answer the core of the question. Thanks

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you are facing,thus unable to resolve it for you,please try the updated answer once more and let me know